# How does Django's `url` template tag reverse a Regex?

Tags: python, regex, django

How does Django's `url` template tag work?  What magic does it use under the covers to "reverse" a regex?

You give it a regex like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

... and then in your template you can generate a URL that matches that pattern like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a>
```

How does that work?  Normally a regex is used to **parse** text, not **generate** it. Are there built-in tools in the `re` module that provide this functionality?

My question is not about how to use Django, or how to parse text with a Regex. Instead I'm interested in learning how I can use regular expressions in this "string template" way elsewhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100870/how-djangos-url-template-tag-works is **not** a duplicate of my question, despite its title.  That question is trying to get something to work right in Django - I'm not.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? How the `urlpatterns` work or how the url template tag works?

Comment: How the `url` template tag works.  I already have a good understanding of how the parsing and dispatching of incoming requests via `urlpatterns` works.  I don't understand how the `url` template tag is able to take that same regex and use it to generate a url.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for! Interesting.

Comment: Oops, sorry deleted my comment since I think I misread exactly what the url tag and reverse tag was responsible for but I'm pretty sure the reverse tag is what does the heavy lifting, hopefully it was helpful anyway!

Comment: Django is open source you know: 
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py#L458
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/base.py#L30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to reversing the regex is the [`normalize()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/regex_helper.py#L50) function, which takes a regex and returns a list of possibilities. Each possibility is a tuple of a placeholder string and a list of parameters.

The `reverse()` function first checks if the parameters match the list of parameters for the placeholder. If it matches, the placeholder string is formatted with the arguments passed to `reverse()` (with a simple `'string' % parameters`). This string is then matched against the original regex. That's necessary because the parameters for the placeholder string don't have any restrictions, so checking against the original regex ensures that e.g. a group with `\d+` only contains numbers.

If a string formatted with the passed parameters matches the original regex, it's a valid url, and returned.